# Powershell script for searching properties for a limited number of users on the AD

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a PS script of a limited number of users. As I have too many users on AD, it's taking a long time.

Anyone knows how to run Script on Limited number of users? *E.g.:* 200

Answer (score 0):

Store the user in a variable, loop over it as you wish:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "*"
$start = 0;
for ($i = $start; $i -lt $start + 200; $i++) { 
  $user[$i] # run your code here
}
```

Now increase `$start` and go again.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of users returned with the `-ResultSetSize` parameter:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -ResultSetSize 200
```

Comment: And how do you specify where to start with the next batch, so you don't get the same user in the next call?